# Ayuda con una consulta de una tabla Oracle

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

estoy tratando de hacer un query de una tabla de registros de prestamos de dinero, tengo que implementar un query que me arroje al valor de ABO_CAP del préstamo con la fecha más mínima  ; la columna NUM_CUO es la que me dice que préstamo en especifico tengo.He estado construyendo el query, y ya logre filtrar y traer los datos esenciales para esta consulta, mostrados en el siguiente pantallazo:

[image: El query me arroja la siguiente consulta]

Ahora el inconveniente es que no se como hacer para que me muestre  solo un registro por NUM_CUO , trayendo solo el registro con la fecha mas mínima (Como esta me esta trayendo todas las fechas de los diferentes NUM_CUO). Por poner el ejemplo: del registro NUM_CUO 4770 que me muestre solo el registro que tiene la fecha 15/06/00; del registro 33945 que me muestre solo el registro que tiene la fecha 30/11/16. (Es decir de esta consulta solo me debe mostrar 3 filas).

A continuación les muestro como llevo el query armado:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT a.NUM_ITM, a.NUM_CUO , b.NOM_CON,b.COD_CON,a.FEC_ITM,a.LIQ_ITM,a.ABO_CAP,a.VLR_ITM,a.PAGOS,a.EST_ITM
      FROM CUOTAS_ITEMS a RIGHT  JOIN CONCEPTOS b ON  a.COD_CON=b.COD_CON 
      WHERE NUM_CUO IN  (SELECT DISTINCT(NUM_CUO) FROM CUOTAS_ITEMS WHERE COD_EPL='OCAS02')  
      ORDER BY a.NUM_CUO) 
WHERE LIQ_ITM = 110 OR LIQ_ITM=153 OR LIQ_ITM = 111 OR LIQ_ITM=154 OR LIQ_ITM = 130 OR LIQ_ITM=230 
AND NUM_CUO IN(

SELECT DISTINCT(NUM_CUO) FROM(
 SELECT MIN(NUM_ITM),NUM_CUO  FROM(
   SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT a.NUM_ITM, a.NUM_CUO , b.NOM_CON,b.COD_CON,a.FEC_ITM,a.LIQ_ITM,a.ABO_CAP,a.VLR_ITM,a.PAGOS,a.EST_ITM
               FROM CUOTAS_ITEMS a RIGHT  JOIN CONCEPTOS b ON  a.COD_CON=b.COD_CON 
               WHERE NUM_CUO IN  (SELECT DISTINCT(NUM_CUO) FROM CUOTAS_ITEMS WHERE COD_EPL='OCAS02')  
               ORDER BY a.NUM_CUO) 
    WHERE LIQ_ITM = 110 OR LIQ_ITM=153 OR LIQ_ITM = 111 OR LIQ_ITM=154 OR LIQ_ITM = 130 OR LIQ_ITM=230

    ORDER BY NUM_ITM)
GROUP BY NUM_CUO
)
)
```

Agradecería mucho que me puedan colaborar, muchas gracias

Comment: La consulta que vos buscas se puede simplificar bastante, pero es necesario saber en que tabla esta cada cosa. Lo ideal seria primero tener un solo registro que tenga la fecha minima y el num_cuo, y despues joinearle todo lo que necesitas. Podrias darnos una estructura minima de lo que tenes (y despues lo joineas vos lo que necesitas)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te complicaste de más al querer repetir la consulta. Puedes obtener el resultado usando ROW_NUMBER(). Y por Dios, dale formato a tu código.

```
SELECT NUM_ITM,
    NUM_CUO,
    NOM_CON,
    COD_CON,
    FEC_ITM,
    LIQ_ITM,
    ABO_CAP,
    VLR_ITM,
    PAGOS,
    EST_ITM
FROM (
    SELECT a.NUM_ITM,
        a.NUM_CUO,
        b.NOM_CON,
        b.COD_CON,
        a.FEC_ITM,
        a.LIQ_ITM,
        a.ABO_CAP,
        a.VLR_ITM,
        a.PAGOS,
        a.EST_ITM,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY a.NUM_CUO ORDER BY a.FEC_ITM
            ) AS ROW_NUM
    FROM CUOTAS_ITEMS a
    RIGHT JOIN CONCEPTOS b ON a.COD_CON = b.COD_CON
    WHERE NUM_CUO IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT (NUM_CUO)
            FROM CUOTAS_ITEMS
            WHERE COD_EPL = 'OCAS02'
            )
    AND a.LIQ_ITM IN( 110, 153, 111, 154, 130, 230)
    ORDER BY a.NUM_CUO
    ) x
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1;
```

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias @Luis Cazares, me ha servido tu solución. De antemano muchas Gracias! .